# Not able to see black and white image after threshold application

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, matplotlib, image-processing

I am working on a project for detecting lines using threshold values in HLS image format. I wrote the following code for it. It is not giving any errors but the output I am getting is just a black image. I tried changing the threshold values and also tried with multiple images.

Can someone please help me with the bug fix?

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import logging
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO, format='%(funcName)s:%(message)s')


class LaneFinding:
    def __init__(self, img):
        self.img = img

    def get_hsl_transform(self, thresh: tuple):
        """
        This method will return a HSL image for the given image for which the pixel values are adjusted between the 
        lower and higher threshold.

        The values between lower and upper threshold will be 1 and all other values will be zero.
        
        :param tuple thresh: Tuple of two values, the lower value threshold and upper threshold for the image.
        
        """
        # Convert the given RGB image to HSL image
        img_hsl = cv2.cvtColor(self.img, cv2.COLOR_RGB2HLS)

        # Separate individula channels in the imge and create zero masks for each channel.
        h = img_hsl[:,:,0]
        l = img_hsl[:,:,1]
        s = img_hsl[:,:,2]

        binary_h = np.zeros_like(img_hsl)
        binary_s = np.zeros_like(img_hsl)
        binary_l = np.zeros_like(img_hsl)

        # Apply threshold to individual channels and make a binary image.
        binary_h[(h>thresh[0]) & (h<=thresh[1])] = 1
        binary_s[(s>thresh[0]) & (s<=thresh[1])] = 1
        binary_l[(l>thresh[0]) & (l<=thresh[1])] = 1

        return binary_h, binary_s, binary_l
    



if __name__ == '__main__':

    # This will only check if the new methods added in the class above work or not. 

    img = cv2.imread(r"Gradient_and_color_space\\bridge_shadow.jpg")
    thresh = (10, 100)

    lane_finding = LaneFinding(img)

    _, binary_s, _ = lane_finding.get_hsl_transform(thresh=thresh)
    plt.imshow(binary_s, cmap='gray')
    plt.show()
```

The result I am getting looks like this.
[image]

And here is the original image
[image]

Comment: Kindly share your image(s).

Comment: I edited the question and added original image in it

Comment: A quick look tells me you will return 0 or 1 for every pixel, which will be very dark on a scale of 0..255. Try returning larger values `return binary_h *255, binary_s *255, binary_l *255`

Comment: I tried that, this creates a different problem. I want my lane markings in the image to be white and everything else black. Multiplying by 255 results in black lane lines and white everything else.

Comment: Then invert the image?

Comment: your color selection logic is broken. you DO select *everything but* those lines. the result IS 68.9% "white". you picked your thresholds wrong. and why DO you use the same limits for both hue, saturation, and level? why do you not pick different limits for each of those channels?

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz I am trying out different things to see what works the best. I am fairly new to the world of image processing. If you can suggest a good approach for my mistakes, I will really appreciate it. It is also fine if you can guide me to some article or paper in which all of this is explained with some reason.